# Multiple Sections In UITableView Swift 4

Tags: swift, uitableview, sections

Well, I am trying to make a registration form. My problem is that in the section cell doesn't show the correct info into the sections, it shows all the info in the sections... ermm I think something I missed on the cell for row.

So, my code would look something like this.

**UITableViewDataSource**

```
extension IEKRegistrationPage3Controller: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IEKRegistrationPage3GraduateCell", for: indexPath) as! IEKRegistrationPage3GraduateCell

    // Graduate
    if let graduate = Graduate(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
        cell.updateLayout(withTitle: graduate.description, isSelected: [graduate] == iekRegistrationFormData.graduate)
        }

    if let student = Student.init(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
        cell.updateLayout(withTitle: student.description, isSelected: [student] == iekRegistrationFormData.student)
    }

    return cell
    }
}
```

Also here is the **UITableViewDelegate**

```
extension IEKRegistrationPage3Controller: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Graduate
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let graduate = Graduate(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
            iekRegistrationFormData.graduate = [graduate]
        }
    }

    // Student
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if let student = Student(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
            iekRegistrationFormData.student = [student]
        }
    }

    // Engilsh
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        // TODO
    }
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

and finally the **titleForHeaderInSection**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    // Graduate
    if section == 0 {
        return "ΑΠΟΦΟΙΤΟΣ"
    }

    // Student
    if section == 1 {
        return "ΦΟΙΤΗΤΗΣ"
    }

    // Engilsh
    if section == 2 {
        return "ΑΓΓΛΙΚΑ"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Your `cellForRowAt` is only look at the `row` of the index path. You need to get the data specific to the section and row and return a cell specific to the section and row.

Comment: Thanks I had to put if indexPath.section == 0 { )   ect ect